# How to group same array values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to group in subarray the identical values ​​while preserving the original order of each group of values.

I want this :

```
array('a','b','b','c','c','c','a','a');
```

to become :

```
array( array('a'),array('b','b'),array('c','c','c'),array('a','a'));
```

Comment: You should have seen by now that SO generally expects you to have a go before asking how to do something.

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = array('a','b','b','c','c','c','a','a');

$tempvalue = false;
$temparr = array();
$new = array();
foreach ($source as $value) {
    if ($tempvalue && $value != $tempvalue){
        $new[] = $temparr;
        $temparr = array();
    }
    $temparr[] = $value;

    $tempvalue = $value;
}
$new[] = $temparr;

echo json_encode($new);
```

output:

```
[["a"],["b","b"],["c","c","c"],["a","a"]]
```